# datetime vanishes from the indicator-datetime

Tags: 15.04, indicator

datetime doesn't appear in the bar by default on Ubuntu 15.04.

After installing indicator-datetime and running the following comment it starts working:

$ dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/datetime/

But if you select "Date and Month" from in Time & Date settings, it vanishes again.